# adding 1 to a binary number using logical operations

Tags: binary, logical-operators

As title describes; I want to add 1 to a  4 bit binary number using only AND OR XOR operations. How can I achieve that?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you're doing when you perform addition of decimal numbers in long-hand. It's exactly the same.

---

Here's how I'd do it, showing a **lot** of working.

Label the four bits from `b0` (least significant bit) to `b3` (most significant bit), and introduce 5 carry bits, `c0` to `c4`. The modified values are `b3', b2', b1', b0'`, so your nibble, the carry bits, and the modified values are:

```
{     b3  b2  b1  b0  }
{ c4  c3  c2  c1  c0  }
{     b3' b2' b1' b0' }
```

and they are related through:

```
c0  = 1 (this is to flip the least significant bit)

b0' = XOR(b0, 1)
c1  = AND(b0, 1)

b1' = XOR(b1, c0)
c2  = AND(b1, c0)

b2' = XOR(b2, c1)
c3  = AND(b2, c1)

b3' = XOR(b3, c2)
c4  = AND(b3, c2)
```

**Note:**

1. There's no need for `OR` to be used.
2. The choice of four bits is arbitrary - beyond the first bit, the logic is [*copy/pasta*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copypasta).
3. When the last carry bit `c3` is `0`, the number is silently [overflowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) (going from `15` to `0`).
4. There's no need to have *four* carry bits, but in keeping with the hand-addition paradigm, I've introduced them anyway.
5. Four bits is a [Nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble).

---

**Sample C# class:**

```
public class Nibble
{
    const int bits = 4;

    private bool[] _bools = new bool[bits];

    public void Reset()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < _bools.Length; i++ )
            _bools[i] = false;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        bool[] result = new bool[bits];
        bool[] carries = new bool[bits + 1];

        carries[0] = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < bits; i++ )
        {
            result[i] = _bools[i] ^ carries[i];
            carries[i + 1] = _bools[i] && carries[i];
        }

        if ( carries[bits] )
            Console.WriteLine("Overflow!");

        _bools = result;
    }

    public byte Value
    {
        get
        {
            byte result = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < bits; i++ )
            {
                if ( _bools[i] )
                    result += (byte)(1 << i);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var nibble = new Nibble();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 17; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nibble.Value);
            nibble.Increment();
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Run on Ideone here](http://ideone.com/X0QIhy)